# Manage Logic App Connections in the Azure Portal

Tags: azure-logic-apps

We are using a SFTP connector for file transfer in our Logic App which will be invoked from a web application. Before invoking it we want to Add/Update the SFTP connection details under API connections. These connection details will be used by SFTP connector. How to achieve this?  Any REST API or SDK? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage all of you connections via the Azure Portal (the resource name is 'API Connections'). Look for 'Edit API Settings' once you open resource blade for any of your connections.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Szymon.. But we want to edit these SFTP API connection details from our web application. We are looking for any REST API or SDK to do this. Let me explain our requirement. We are triggering logic app from a web application.Before invoking it we want to modify SFTP connection details from web application based on the client info. . So that we will have single logic app will be used for multiple clients.

Comment: Have you considered just deploying a new copy of the connection and logic apps for each client? You can achieve this quite easily by automating your deployments with Azure Resource Manager (a sample template is available here: https://github.com/jeffhollan/logicapps-deployments/blob/master/ftp_to_blob.json).

Comment: If you really want to follow your original approach (modify the connection), I don't believe than an SDK is available, but you can use the REST APIs. The resource id for your connection would be of the form subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/{connectionName}, and the API supports GET/PUT/DELETE verbs. You need to use an Azure AD bearer token for authentication (against the https://management.azure.com endpoint).